# how to know if lines intersect in uibezierPath?

Tags: ios, swift, uibezierpath, cashapelayer

I have a code that, by tapping on the screen, adds a point and connects it with a line using UIBezierPath.

```
var lassoBezier: UIBezierPath?
    var lassoPoints: [CGPoint] = []
    func addPont(point: CGPoint) {
        guard let lassoBezier = lassoBezier else {
            lassoBezier = UIBezierPath()
            addPont(point: point)
            return
        }
        if lassoPoints.isEmpty {
            lassoBezier.move(to: point)
        } else {
            lassoBezier.addLine(to: point)
        }
        lassoPoints.append(point)
        let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayer.path = lassoBezier.cgPath
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = 4
        imageView?.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
    }
```

Is it possible to find out that 2 lines have crossed? And where did they intersect?

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://github.com/adamwulf/ClippingBezier. Are you looking to see intersection of 2 separate UIBezierPaths, or checking if a newly added point intersects with the existing path?

Comment: This link has code that returns the intersection point of two lines, or `nil` if they don't cross: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/core-graphics/how-to-calculate-the-point-where-two-lines-intersect

Comment: @mani i need to know when the lines intersect within one UIBezierPaths and the point of their intersection

Comment: @RomanGorbatko - did either of those links give you a solution?